# Retrieve Manager name for each user in AD using powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to dump an OU (Staff) in our AD to a specific format

```
"name" -> "Manager";
```

I am zeroing in but I'm hitting a wall with the following code

```
get-aduser -filter * -SearchBase "OU=Staff,DC=whatever,DC=local" |  get-aduser -Properties Manager | Select Name,Manager
```

The output for manager is returned as:

```
CN=Sharon Doe,OU=Staff,DC=whatever,DC=local
```

Also I am unsure how to wrap the text in quotes and insert the arrow between name and manger

Thanks if you can point me in the right direction

this is my sudo working code so far

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory  
 $users = $null
 $i = $null  
 $users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "ou=Staff,dc=whatever,dc=local" -filter * `  -property description  
 ForEach($user in $users)  
  {  

      $user.name + >>>Get-ADUser($users.manager).name**<<<

      $i++  

 }  
"$i users"
```

Comment: Yes, the `manager` property is the *distinguished name* of the manager's user object - to get the manager's name, you need to find that object (bind to it) and then retrieve it's name

Comment: Seems logical, How do I do that?

Comment: See the response below - Mathias beat me to the response (and his is much better than mine ever would have been :-) )

Comment: I updated the answer with the code using only parts i understand. the part marked in the >>>><<<< brackets is what i don't understand is not work

Comment: @Crash893 updated my answer with an example using a `foreach` loop

Answer (score 12):

You can use

```
(Get-ADUser "CN=Sharon Doe,OU=Staff,DC=whatever,DC=local").DisplayName
```

to fetch the manager's user object and grab the `DisplayName` instead of the DN.

If you don't feel confident working with [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) (see below), you can use it inside a `foreach` loop:

```
$Users = Get-ADUser -filter * -SearchBase "OU=Staff,DC=whatever,DC=local" -Properties Manager 

foreach($User in $Users){
    $Manager = Get-ADUser $User.Manager -Properties DisplayName
    $ManagerName = $Manager.DisplaýName

    "$($User.Name) -> $ManagerName"
}
```

---

You could also use it inside a calculated property when using `Select-Object`:

```
$Users = Get-ADUser -filter * -SearchBase "OU=Staff,DC=whatever,DC=local" -Properties Manager 
$Users | Select Name,@{label="Manager";expression={(Get-ADUser $_.Manager -Properties DisplayName).DisplayName}}
```

---

If the `Select` statement gets too unreadable, you can always make a [splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx) table with the properties:

```
$NameManager = @{
  "Property" = @(
    "Name"
    @{
      Label = "Manager"
      Expression = {
        Get-ADUser $_.Manager -Properties DisplayName |Select -Expand DisplayName
      }
    }
  )
}

$Users | Select-Object @NameManager
```

Comment: I updated the answer with the code using only parts i understand. the part marked in the >>>><<<< brackets is what i don't understand is not work

Comment: @Crash893 You need to wrap the `Get-ADUser` call into one more set of round brackets. `"$($user.name) -> $((Get-ADUser($users.manager)).name)"` The `$(expression)` syntax in a string inserts the expression value in the indicated place.

Comment: @Vesper  Its almost there but I am getting an error

Comment: Get-ADUser : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser' required by parameter 'Identity'. Specified method 
is not supported.
At C:\Users\administrator.whatever\Desktop\orgchart test.ps1:8 char:50
+       write-host $($user.name) "->" $((Get-ADUser($users.manager)).name)
+                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

Comment: @mathias R. Jessen, you for script runs but two things happen 1) no user has a manager and 2) oddly some users error out i confirmed that they users that error out do have managers

Comment: To be honest, I think the attribute you're after is called managedBy, not Manager

Comment: Calculated Properties was exactly what I was looking for. Worked like a charm, Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the calculated property, saved me loads of syntax trial and error!

Answer (score 2):

I use PowerShell regex to filter only the friendly name portion of the manager from the DN for the "Manger" attribute in the AD user object properties, see below:

```
$newUser = Get-ADUser -Identity someUser1 -Properties *
$newUser.Manager
```

Output:
CN=Some Manager1,OU=IT,DC=YOUR,DC=DOMAIN,DC=COM

```
$newUser.Manager.split(',')[0].trim('CN=')
```

Output:

```
Some Manager1
```

In addition, you could use the following filter as well, but I feel it is more code than necessary, trim does what we want with less typing and complexity (Not going into why one is better than the other, we haven't talked scale about this ask):

```
CN=someUser1,OU=IT,DC=YOUR,DC=DOMAIN,DC=COM
$newUser.Manager.split(',')[0] -replace 'CN=',''
```

Output:

```
Some Manager1
```

For completeness, you should know the type of your final state, you can get this with the following:

```
($newUser.Manager.split(',')[0].trim('CN=')).GetType()
```

OR

```
($newUser.Manager.split(',')[0] -replace 'CN=','').GetType()
```

Output:

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                                           
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                                           
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

Now you know your final value is of type 'string'!

Lastly, you can trap your value in a variable:

```
$Mgr = $newUser.Manager.split(',')[0].trim('CN=')
```

Okay, I found a bug in my regex using trim logic, if an user has a DN that starts like the following:

```
CN=Nicholas
```

Then the output using $newUser.Manager.split(',')[0].trim('CN=') is as follows:

```
icholas
```

This is because trim truncates any matching character, not the whole string specified, where as -replace does it based on the string as shown below:

```
$newUser.Manager.split(',')[0] -replace 'CN=',''
```

Output:

```
Nicholas
```

**FINAL SOLUTION:** So, I recommend the following as a final solution:

```
$newUser.Manager.split(',')[0] -replace 'CN=',''
```

My apologies for the oversight, I now remember seeing others mention this online and I completely forgot about it. Once again, I apologize for the confusion.

Enjoy!