# Get Manager's CN directly

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm getting properties for a user, one of them being the manager. However, I only want the manager's name (CN). With my current code, `$stdManager` is a string: `CN=first last,OU=...,etc,etc`. The simple answer is to just parse the string, the problem is, the active directory I'm working with is very inconsistent with formatting, meaning some managers are `CN=John Smith,OU=...` and others are `CN=Smith\, John,OU=...` which also causes a headache considering I'm putting this info into a comma delimited csv. Instead of parsing this string and doing a bunch of error checking for format, is there a way I can do `$stdManager = $stdUser.manager.CN`? Now that I think about it, if such a method exists, I would still run into the issue of `Smith\, John` breaking my csv file. Any tips on handling all of this in a concise manner?

```
$stdUser = Get-ADUser $stdSAM -Properties *
$stdManager = $stdUser."manager"
$stdMail = $stdUser."mail"
$d1 = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($stdUser."lastLogonTimestamp")
# etc, etc
```

Comment: the usual way to get that info is to add a call to `Get-ADUser` using the manager info you have. [*grin*]

Comment: In addition to that, it is bad practice to do `-Properties *`. Better add the list of properties you are after there instead of asking for all of them. Also, if you use property `LastLogonDate` instead of `lastLogonTimestamp` you don't have to convert to a local time [DateTime] object because that is already done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve Manager name for each user in AD using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31325725/retrieve-manager-name-for-each-user-in-ad-using-powershell)

Comment: Thanks, I was looking to avoid doing another `Get-ADUser` and doing something like `user.manager.cn` but it seems this isn't possible