# How can I find the manager's details for each user who is an ADGroupMember

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to use PowerShell to display the name of the Manager of each Active member of an AD Group, e.g.

**This method works for a single user:**

```
    Get-ADUser C567890X -Properties * | Select Name, GivenName, Surname, 
    @{ N = "Manager"; E = { (Get-ADUser $PSItem.Manager -Property DisplayName).DisplayName } } `
    | Sort GivenName, Surname
```

| Name | GivenName | Surname | Manager |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C567890X | Thomas | Sawyer | Mark Twain |

**This method also works for a single user:**

```
    Get-ADUser B3456789 -Properties Name, GivenName, Surname, Manager `
    | Select @{ N = 'Account#'; E = {$_.Name} }, @{ N ='FirstName'; E = {$_.GivenName} }, 
    @{ N ='LastName'; E = {$_.Surname} }, @{ N = 'Manager'; 
    E = { ([ADSI]"LDAP://$($_.Manager)").DisplayName -Replace ' \(.*$' } } `
    | Sort FirstName, LastName
```

| Account# | FirstName | LastName | Manager |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B3456789 | Huckleberry | Finn | Mark Twain |

**Domain Group Properties**

`'CN=GG ELEV Local Admin Perms,OU=Group Policy,OU=Groups,OU=Administrative,DC=MyDomain,DC=local'`

```
    Get-ADGroupMember "GG ELEV Local Admin Perms" -Recursive `
    | ForEach{Get-ADUser $_} | Where-Object {$PSItem.Enabled} `
    | Select Name, GivenName, Surname | Sort GivenName, Surname `
    | Out-String -Width 100
```

| Name | GivenName | Surname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1234567 | Mark | Twain |
| B3456789 | Huckleberry | Finn |
| C567890X | Thomas | Sawyer |

**Required output for entire Group "GG ELEV Local Admin Perms":**

| Account# | FirstName | LastName | Manager |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1234567 | Mark | Twain | Samuel Langhorne Clemens |
| B3456789 | Huckleberry | Finn | Mark Twain |
| C567890X | Thomas | Sawyer | Mark Twain |

**I have tried:**

```
    Get-ADGroupMember "GG ELEV Local Admin Perms" -Recursive | ForEach {Get-ADUser $_} `
    | Where-Object {$PSItem.Enabled} | Select Name, GivenName, Surname, @{ N = "Manager"; 
    E = { (Get-ADUser $PSItem.Manager).DisplayName -Replace ' \(.*$' } } `
    | Sort GivenName, Surname | Out-String -Width 100
```

| Name | GivenName | Surname | Manager |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1234567 | Mark | Twain | ***BLANK*** |
| B3456789 | Huckleberry | Finn | ***BLANK*** |
| C567890X | Thomas | Sawyer | ***BLANK*** |

**I have also tried:**

```
    Get-ADGroupMember "GG ELEV Local Admin Perms" -Recursive | ForEach {Get-ADUser $_} `
    | Where-Object {$PSItem.Enabled} | Select @{ N = 'Account#'; E = {$_.Name} }, @{ N ='FirstName'; 
    E = $_.GivenName} }, @{ N ='LastName'; E = {$_.Surname} }, @{ N = 'Manager'; 
    E = { ([ADSI]"LDAP://$($_.Manager)").DisplayName -Replace ' \(.*$' } } `
    | Sort FirstName, Lastname | Out-String -Width 100
```

| Account# | FirstName | LastName | Manager |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1234567 | Mark | Twain | ***BLANK*** |
| B3456789 | Huckleberry | Finn | ***BLANK*** |
| C567890X | Thomas | Sawyer | ***BLANK*** |

So far, with the above two `Get-ADGroupMember` methods I have tried, the Manager's name always appears blank.

Please can somebody advise me how I can get the Manager's name against the listing of each of the Group's members, using a combination of the above two methods, i.e. piping the Manager property from the `Get-ADGroupMember` command's output through the Calculated Property to display the Manager's name (in one script)?

I have built the above scripts using suggestions from various sources, including the link below, but I think I've missed something (I'm still learning PowerShell)
[Retrieve Manager name for each user in AD using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31325725/retrieve-manager-name-for-each-user-in-ad-using-powershell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each of your `Get-ADUser $_` parts, you also need to request the "Manager" property

`Get-ADUser $_ -properties manager`

This worked for your "one user" option as you had requested **all** properties in that line.

Example:

```
Get-ADGroupMember "GG ELEV Local Admin Perms" -Recursive `
| ForEach{Get-ADUser $_ -properties manager} | Where-Object {$PSItem.Enabled} `
| Select Name, GivenName, Surname, Manager | Sort GivenName, Surname `
| Out-String -Width 100
```

Explanation: when you use the `Get-ADUser` method, you only get back a basic few properties:

> DistinguishedName, Enabled, GivenName, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID, Surname, UserPrincipalName

source: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12037.active-directory-get-aduser-default-and-extended-properties.aspx

As you don't get the "Manager" property, you need to request it specifically, which you do with the `-Properties x,y,z` option, where x, y, and z are properties you want. If you want every property, you can use the asterisk `*` instead. `Get-ADUser johnny -Properties *`

Comment: That's excellent, it has resolved the issue and I can now obtain the Manager's detaisl successfully in my report. I knew it would be quite a simple fix, just not properly familiar with PowerShell syntax yet - I'm still learning. Many thanks for this @Guy-S I've marked this as the answer. Much obliged and a Happy New Year to you from a grateful Ifte. 