# Powershell: Using if/else statements with Expressions in custom properties

Tags: powershell, active-directory

This is off of a similar premise to [Retrieve Manager name for each user in AD using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31325725)

Question: When defining the Expression value for custom properties, can we include either a try/catch or an if condition to handle errors and/or capture details of errors for logging purposes, without messing up the expression value itself?

Details: In the code below, we pass the manager property back into `Get-ADUser` to retrieve the sAMAccountName of the managers:

```
Start-Transcript -Path 'c:\temp\log.txt' -Force
## List of AD user objects
$OU = "OU=Users,DC=company,DC=com"
$Users = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter '(&(objectCategory=Person)(sAMAccountName=*))' -SearchBase $OU -Properties *

## this array will make sense later...
$missingMgrs = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()

## Defined properties through splatting:
$ChosenProperties = @{
  "Property" = @(
    # built-in attributes:
    'Name', 'sAMAccountName', 'EmailAddress'
    # custom attributes below:
    @{
      Label = "ManagerSAmAccountName"
      Expression = { 
        Get-ADUser $_.Manager -Properties DisplayName |Select -Expand sAMAccountName  
      }      
    }
  )
}

$Users | Select-Object @ChosenProperties
Stop-Transcript
```

An excerpt from the transcript might look like this:

```
Name              sAMAccountName EmailAddress              ManagerSAmAccountName
----              -------------- ------------              ---------------------
Person One        pone           pone@company.com          managera
Person Two        ptwo           ptwo@company.com          managerb
>> TerminatingError(Get-ADUser): "Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again."
Person Three      pthree         pthree@company.com        
>> TerminatingError(Get-ADUser): "Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again."
Person Four       pfour          pfour@company.com         
Person Five       pfive          pfive@company.com         managera
```

Since Persons 3 and 4 have no manager, the custom expression is calling `Get-ADUser` against a null manager value.

I thought I could swap out the Expression with an if statement to only call `Get-ADUser` if the manager existed, and value-added, to log which user had this issue:

```
      Expression = {   
          if ($($_.Manager.Length) -gt 0) {
          Get-ADUser $_.Manager -Properties DisplayName |Select -Expand sAMAccountName 
          } else {
              $missingMgrs.Add("$($_.Name) is missing a manager.")
          }
        }
```

and at the end, just before stopping transcript:

```
Write-Output $missingMgrs
```

However, that generates the results like this:

```
Name              sAMAccountName EmailAddress              ManagerSAmAccountName
----              -------------- ------------              ---------------------
Person One        pone           pone@company.com          managera
Person Two        ptwo           ptwo@company.com          managerb
>> TerminatingError(Get-ADUser): "Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again."
Person Three      pthree         pthree@company.com        0
>> TerminatingError(Get-ADUser): "Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again."
Person Four       pfour          pfour@company.com         1
Person Five       pfive          pfive@company.com         managera
[...]
Person Three is missing a manager.
Person Four is missing a manager.
```

Although the if/else did succeed in logging the manager-less users, it did not stop the `Get-ADUser` line from running on these entries.  Also, the expression for `ManagerSAmAccountName` now evaluates as incrementing integers versus $null.

Back to the original question:  Is there a way to write a custom property using an if/else so that the Expression's value gets evaluated only when the if condition is met?

Thanks!

Comment: im surprised that you are seeing terminating errors coming from the expression block because, as you can see: `'' | Select-Object @{ N = 'Test'; E = { throw 'hi' }}`, terminating errors are completely ignored in that context. As aside, in your LDAP filter `(objectCategory=Person)` is what `Get-ADUser` defaults to so it can be removed

Answer (score 1):

Regarding:

> Also, the expression for `ManagerSAmAccountName` now evaluates as incrementing integers versus `$null`.

This is because [`.Add(..)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist.add?view=net-8.0#system-collections-arraylist-add(system-object)) from [`ArrayList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=net-8.0) outputs an integer representing the index where the item was added. To fix this, change it for a [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-8.0) instead (see code).

---

Going back to the main issue, I have no explanation as to why you're seeing exceptions in your transcript, specially because terminating errors are completely ignored in the context of a expression block:

```bash
'' | Select-Object @{ N = 'Test'; E = { throw 'hi' } }

# Test
# ----
#
```

See [**Notes**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.4#notes):

> - **For most cmdlets, errors inside expression script blocks are quietly ignored**. For `Sort-Object`, statement-terminating and script-terminating errors are output but they don't terminate the statement.

What I can provide you is with code that will not throw any errors, I have also added a caching mechanism so that you're not querying managers that have been already queried, mainly for efficiency purposes.

```bash
Start-Transcript -Path 'c:\temp\log.txt' -Force

$getADUserSplat = @{
    LDAPFilter = '(sAMAccountName=*)'
    SearchBase = 'OU=Users,DC=company,DC=com'
    Properties = 'EmailAddress', 'Manager'
}

## this array will make sense later...
$missingMgrs = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
$managerCache = @{}

Get-ADUser @getADUserSplat | ForEach-Object {
    # if `.Manager` is populated and has not yet been added to the cache
    if ($_.Manager -and -not $managerCache.ContainsKey($_.Manager)) {
        $managerCache[$_.Manager] = try {
            ($_.Manager | Get-ADUser).SamAccountName
        }
        catch {
            # `catch` block is left empty here in case the manager's distinguishedName
            # points to a deleted object.
            # can also include here adding to `$missingMgrs` if needed, see below:
            # $missingMgrs.Add("$($_.Exception.Message): $($_.TargetObject)")
        }
    }
    else {
        $missingMgrs.Add("$($_.Name) is missing a manager.")
    }

    [pscustomobject]@{
        Name                  = $_.Name
        sAMAccountName        = $_.sAMAccountName
        EmailAddress          = $_.EmailAddress
        # the `[string]` cast here avoids getting an exception if `.Manager` was null
        ManagerSAmAccountName = $managerCache[[string] $_.Manager]
    }
}

Stop-Transcript
```

Comment: Incredible!  Thank you so much for sharing good coding patterns.  There is so much to learn from here.